# Error 503 Service temporarily unavailable with home internet connection but works with mobile data

Tags: networking, docker, http, 503-error

I'm running some apps under docker on Oracle cloud free-tier ARM64 server. I'm using an nginx reverse proxy and wildcard subdomains to access the apps.

When I try to access the app at port.meracloud.tk using my home internet connection, I get a "503 Service temporarily unavailable" error(both on my phone and laptop). However, when I use the mobile data on my phone, I can access myapp.

The weirdest part is that if I connect my laptop to my phone's hotspot and use my home internet through my phone connected to home WiFi, I can access the app but if I try connecting the laptop to the home WiFi directly, I go back to 503 error.

Any ideas what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that in the DDNS service I'm using, the IPV4 address for the server was getting updated but the IPV6 address wasn't and the IPV6 address was pointing to another server of mine.

I suspected some foul play with IPV6 as using mobile data was working and mobile data used IPV4. My home internet connection on the other hand is IPV6 and so it was ending up at the wrong address